# How to Use Nested foreach or for

Tags: php, html, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have a html, and I want to insert this form to table. this view html :

[image]

form on above is dynamic,I want to insert this data to MySQL, I have been tried with this :

```html
$id_po = $_POST['id_po'];
        $id_model = $_POST['id_model'];
        $id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];
        $id_model_jml = count($id_model);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $id_model_jml; $i++) {
            $ukuran = $_POST['ukuran'][$i];
            $jumlah_hanca = $_POST['jumlah_hanca'];
            $jumlah_hanca_jml = count($jumlah_hanca);
            for ($x = 0; $x < $jumlah_hanca_jml; $x++) {
                $qry = $db->query("INSERT INTO hanca SET id_hanca=NULL, 
                       id_po='$id_po', id_model='$id_model[$i]', ukuran='$ukuran[$x]',
                       jumlah_hanca='$jumlah_hanca[$x]', id_user='$id_user' ");
                if ($qry) {
                    echo "berhasil simpan hanca";
                } else {
                    echo "gagal simpan hanca";
                }
            }
        }
```

what are the methods I want to use?

Comment: What database are you using? In MySQL this query string would result in an error for syntax based on using 'SET' with an insert statement. You need to use syntax like this for inserts:.       Insert into table (columna, columnb, columnc) values (valuea, valueb, valuec);            the keyword SET is used for update statements.